# Android Design Best Practice

Tags: java, android, service, process, alarmmanager

I am in the process of designing my first Android application and have a best practices/design question. So not necessarily looking for code, but for someone to lead me in the right direction as far as research goes.

I am looking to have an application where a user kicks off a timer. When that timer has expired, the application will run some code. I need the timer to continue to run even when the user closes the application and/or reboots the phone. So even if the phone dies, once it is charged and turned back on I need my application to kick off and recognize the timer has expired and run some code or continue counting down (essentially checking to see if a particular date and time has been reached). In addition, I want the user to be able to re-launch the application and end the timer pre-maturely if desired.

I thought I was on the right track by creating a local service in a seperate process but further research shows that may not be best practice and to look into alarm manager with broadcast. So my question to the masses...what route should I be tacking to achieve my goal?

Thoughts/Suggestions? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you make your title and question more to the point ? What's the specific question ?

Answer (score 3):

> I thought I was on the right track by creating a local service in a seperate process

That is an anti-pattern (everlasting service) on top of an anti-pattern (separate process).

> what route should I be tacking to achieve my goal?

Use `AlarmManager`, plus a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`. The `BroadcastReceiver` can detect missed events, plus set up a fresh `AlarmManager` schedule.